# Can I run MySQL and Postgresql together on a VPS?

Tags: mysql, vps

I'd like to know if anybody has any experience with this. I have a VPS server with ruby On rails, nginx and pgsql.
I'd like to use Wordpress on it too, and the biggest issue seems to be running it on postgresql.

So, do you think I can run two databases on one VPS, considering the VPS is 512MB and the sites are not very much visited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a customer server (Ubuntu 10.04, 64 Bit) with Postgres and MySQL running at the same time. It is very important that you configure both database servers accordingly to your RAM. 
The server I am using is equipped with 4 GB RAM, which causes Ubuntu to use the SWAP from time to time.

512 MB RAM for all your applications seems to be very low - I can only advice you to try it out and gain some field experience.

By the way, a default wordpress database only consums 2-3 MB (without the custom content, ofc).

Comment: thanks will try it as soon as i get the damn php running :)

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that any DBMS want to cache frequently requested data in the RAM. Mysql caches indices and query results for recycling. If My and Pg begin fight for the RAM you'll see a rising disk i/o that slows down your service.

You can try to limit RAM consumption of My by my.cnf and inspect what happens. May be, you DB is small enough to fit into 100Mb.